# Let $T_1$ be an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. Show that $T_1^2$ is a biased estimator of $\theta^2$.

Tags: statistics, expectation, estimation, variance

Let $T$ be an unbiased estimator of $\theta$. Show that $T^2$
is a biased estimator of $\theta^2$.

We have $\operatorname{E}(T)=\theta$ by assumption. Then $\operatorname{E}(T^2)=\operatorname{Var}(T)+(\operatorname{E}(T))^2=\operatorname{Var}(T)+\theta^2$.
But we can't guarantee $\operatorname{Var}(T)$ is not zero. How can the question be answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\operatorname{Var}(T) = 0$, then $T$ is a constant, which means your estimator is a constant random variable that's just "the right answer" ($\theta$) with probability 1. My guess is that it's safe to assume this isn't the case.

(But if it somehow *is* the case, then yes -- $T^2$ would indeed be an unbiased estimator of $\theta^2$.)

Answer (score 0):

We have E(T)=θ by assumption. 
Now, 
Var(T)>0
or, E(T^2)-E^2(T)>0
or, E(T^2)>E^2(T)
Or, E(T^2)>θ^2
Hence, E(T^2)≠θ^2
Hence T^2 is a biased estimator of θ^2

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).